# How to tell if an app is calling a system function and debug it

Tags: usb-debugging

Super noob here for android. I have a dice app and I don't trust it! I want to see what is generating the numbers that it gives (1 through 6 each roll). To start with I was thinking I would see if it calls whatever system/math function android has for rand() (I assume there is one).
I don't have a version of the app with debugging enabled. Can I put a breakpoint (or whatever we call them these days) inside the system's rand() function to see if it gets called?
Thanks!

Comment: Root your device, install Xposed and hook into whatever system APIs you want to track.

Comment: Typically Dice applications aren't very complicated any may be even not obfuscated. Then you can simple decompile it using e.g. Jadx and check which Java functions are used. Alternatively inject Frida into the app so that you can trace or hook functions to se when they are called and if the result is the shown output.